# Can I answer bash-tagged questions with Python one-liners?

Tags: discussion

Many questions tagged with `bash` have accepted answers using `sed`, `awk` or common *NIX utilities.  Is it OK to use Python to answer questions in the same way?

In particular, I'm looking at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987138/how-to-replace-text-randomly-from-file) that wants to randomly bring lines from one text file into another.  I first thought of doing something in Python and then turning it into a one-liner, so it can be executed from the command line, but I'm not sure if this is acceptable on the site.

Comment: As I'm currently learning `python` I'm eagerly awaiting your answer there now. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Yes

Often people use [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash) when they actually mean [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) – I bet that's what terdon had in mind when he [asked about it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987138/how-to-replace-text-randomly-from-file#comment1589921_987138).

Unless OP *explicitly* states they need a *pure* `bash` solution, answers using external tools like `awk`, `sed` and also `python` are welcome and regularly accepted in the end. And even then: **Answers are** not for OP alone, but **for everybody** with the same question. If something else than pure `bash` is in any way useful to solve the problem. then it's suitable for an answer.

After all, there are few who actually *know* what is a `bash` builtin and what's not – a regular Ubuntu user deliberately doesn't have to care about things like that. (There's `type` to determine that, compare the output of `type -a read` with that of `type -a ls`.)

By the way, of the three answers there only *one* uses `bash` builtins, and one of the others is by a *moderator* (watch out for the diamond symbol ♦) – if in doubt, do what [terdon ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) or any other moderator does.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Definitely. Go for it. Lots of people do that.

Python answers work on Ubuntu, so they are helpful to our visitors. In fact, they might even help people who (shhh!) don't use Linux at all.

Just don't expect to get an accept (imho you should never *expect* an accept anyway), because Python might not be what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Done and dusted... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

IMHO tags are only there to help people find the question. Functional solutions shouldn't be avoided simply because they don't match a tag. First of all, questions are often mis-tagged at their inception, and secondly, any answer that results in the desired behavior has value. This is made clear in [the guidelines.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Note: **or a viable alternative.**